# Приходит странный Дикшенери

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Помогите разобраться с севера приходит вот такой дикшенери, необходимо достать из него координаты.

```
2016-10-09 13:40:04.022 MapOfEurope[3145:1024590] (
    (
            (
        "31.191409",
        "-22.25151"
    ),
            (
        "32.654886",
        "-18.67209"
    ),
            (
        "32.611994",
        "-19.419383"
    ),
            (
        "32.772708",
        "-19.715592"
    ),
            (
        "32.659743",
        "-20.30429"
    ),
            (
        "32.508693",
        "-20.395292"
    ),
            (
        "32.244988",
        "-21.116489"
    ),
            (
        "31.191409",
        "-22.25151"
    )
)
```

Не знаю что с ним делать, ключей нет...

Comment: А что бы вы хотели с ним сделать?

Comment: Мне необходимо достать координаты.

Comment: Укажите это в самом вопросе.

Comment: Если ключей нет — это список. _Ваш К. О._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже указали в комментарии - это массив. Распарсить его можно например так

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"1",@"2"],@[@"3",@"4"]];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"lat %@", obj[0]);
    NSLog(@"lon %@", obj[1]);
}];
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо